# Remove an arbitrary element from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

In my Google Maps application I can place markers on the map, and I keep a reference to each of the markers placed, along with some extra information in an array called `markers`.

Adding markers is easy, I just `push()` the newly created object onto the array (`markers.push(marker)`);

However, when it comes to removing an arbitrary marker from the array, given an index of the slot, it doesn't behave as expected. My function is:

```
function deleteMarker(markerIndex) {
    if (markerIndex!='' && markerIndex>=0 && markerIndex<markers.length) {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to remove this marker from the map?')) {
            alert('deleting marker '+markerIndex); //debugging purposes
            markers.splice (markerIndex, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no previous experience with the splice() function, but looking at [its description @ w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) it seems to be pretty straight-forward. However, I get the following behaviour:

`markers.splice()` does nothing. So what am I doing wrong?

And also, when `markerIndex` is 0 no confirmation box is shown. At first I assumed the lengthy if-condition evaluated to false and so the whole code block was skipped, however, using Firebug to step through the calls I found out that the condition holds (of course) for index 0 when array is non-empty, next step reveals that the `if (confirm(...))` and `alert('deleting...)` are *skipped* and `markers.splice()` is called (but nothing happens). This behaviour is so strange I decided to open this question.

*Can anyone please clarify what's going on?*

I thought that deleting markers will be the easiest bit of functionality one could do. I can add them, edit their contents, even *clear all markers* (`pop()`-ing markers off the `markers` array until empty) and all works nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your code is that JavaScript interprets `0 == ''` as true, so for a `markerIndex` of zero, your confirm-code is not executed. I guess that you misinterpreted the steps Firebug shows or that it simply is buggy here since your if-condition will in fact evaluate to false for a markerIndex of 0.

You can use **type-strict comparison** by adding an extra `=`:

```
if (markerIndex !== '' && ...) {
```

An easier approach would be:

```
if (markers[markerIndex] !== undefined) {
```

Since JavaScript does not raise an error when accessing undefined object members.

Your other problem with `splice()` not working is weird (it should work).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This should take care of the 0 index problem :) I keep trying the splice() function. Seems to work but the results are odd... I think I am on the right track and will figure it out myself. Was just really baffled by what Firebug showed... Can't trust it too much :)

Comment: In reaction to: "Your other problem with splice() not working is weird (it should work)." Yes, you are right. It does :$

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteMarker(markerIndex) {
    if (markers[markerIndex] !== undefined) {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to remove this marker from the map?')) {
            map.removeOverlay(markers[markerIndex]);
            markers.splice (markerIndex, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to take care of all the problems. Thanks for your answers, much appreciated.
I especially like the idea of reducing the first if-condition to just:

`if (markers[markerIndex] !== undefined)`

`splice()` seems to operate directly on the array (contrary to what NuclearDog hinted) and it works as expected. My dearest Firebug mislead me.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this is what is happening here. but i've seen the same code run differently in firebug when it is being debugged v when it is not being debugged. i'm pretty sure i had no watches that were interfering with the code either.

Comment: You're right. Firebug is one of the most helpful little plugins but is also a source of great irritation for me from time to time. The weird Firebug behaviour seems to have not much to do with my code.